# SQL: data aren't found

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to get data created next sql query:

```
select groups.name, members.status 
from `members` 
    inner join `groups` on groups.group_id = members.group_id 
where `user_id` = 1
```

I have two tables in my application.
Table `Members`:
  [image]

And Table `Groups`:
[image]

I use a package `mysql` of NodeJS for work with MySQL.

I am trying to get the data in function:

```
function getGroups(req, res) {

    const sql = 'select groups.name, members.status from `members` inner join `groups` on groups.group_id = members.group_id where `user_id` = 1';
    connection.query(sql, (err, results) => {
      console.log(req.payload.id);
      console.log(results);
        if (err) {
            res.status(400);
        }

        if (results && results.length > 0) {
            res.status(200).json(results);
        }

        if (results && results.length === 0) {
            res.status(200).json('Empty');
        }
    });
}
```

Why aren't data found ? Please, help me.
I was used for writting sql query a SQL Tutorial:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: Is there any errors ? Is result empty ?

Comment: No any errors, because I checked my sql query in online validator.  In console I am getting a `undefined` instead of `Empty`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your query is ambiguous and this makes db confuse and it's not returning anything you have user_id in your both the tables and you wrote `where user_id = 1` that may be the case try to console error and your code should be like this..

```
function getGroups(req, res) {

    const sql = 'select g.name, m.status from members m inner join groups g on g.group_id = m.group_id where g.user_id = 1';
    //use g.user_id or m.user_id whatever you want.
    connection.query(sql, (err, results) => {
      console.log(req.payload.id);
      console.log(results);
        if (err) {
            res.status(400);
        }

        if (results && results.length > 0) {
            res.status(200).json(results);
        }

        if (results && results.length === 0) {
            res.status(200).json('Empty');
        }
    }); }
```

> It's Always good to give alias of the table when you are using complex
>   queries
>   [See this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-alias-syntax.htm)
>   Hopefully this will help

Comment: Many thanks for answer. You saved to me many free time. Today I am reading about `Alias`.

Comment: Nice detailed answer!